# ASP.NET MVC InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code while following book example

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
namespace SportsStore.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Product
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a product name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]

        //[Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter a description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        //[Range(0.01, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a positive price")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify a category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the entity definition, and below is action from a controller.

```
    public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1)
    {
        ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel
        {
            Products = repository.Products.Where(p => category == null || p.Category == category).OrderBy(p => p.ProductID).Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize),

            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = category == null ? repository.Products.Count() : repository.Products.Where(e => e.Category == category).Count()
            },

            CurrentCategory = category
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

I get InvalidOperationException complain from Visual Studio when I uncomment [Required...] in Product class. But it works fine with as it is(commented).

I tried to fix it and googled it but can't solve this problem by myself.

Thanks in advance.